# using class methods as celery tasks

Tags: python, django-celery

I'm trying to use the methods of class as the django-celery tasks, marking it up using @task decorator. The same situation is discribed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8846489/celery-python-object-methods), asked by Anand Jeyahar. 
It's something like this

```
class A:
    @task
    def foo(self, bar):
        ...

def main():
    a = A()
    ...
    # what i need
    a.foo.delay(bar) # executes as celery task 
    a.foo(bar) # executes locally
```

The problem is even if i use class instance like this `a.foo.delay(bar)` it says, that `foo` needs at least two arguments, which meens that `self` pointer misses.

More information:

- I can't convert class to *module* because of inheritance
- Methods are strongly depended on class members, so i can't make them *static*
- Marking *class* as the task with @task decorator makes the class a task itself, and it could be possible to execute the methods from `run()` method, using some argument as a key for method selection, but it's not exactly what i want.
- Creating an instance of class and passing it as `self` argument to methods changes the way i execute the methods *not* as celery taks, but as usual methods (i.e. while testing)
- I've tried to find out how i can register the task dinamically, from constructor for example, but celery shares the code between the workers, so that's why it seems to be impossible.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: how do you execute it?  the same examples works for me.

Comment: `a = A()`
`a.method(1,2)` or `a.method.delay(1,2)` -- the result is the same

Answer (score 55, accepted):

Celery has experimental support for using methods as tasks since version 3.0.

The documentation for this is in `celery.contrib.methods`, and also mentions some caveats you should be aware of:

https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/3.1/reference/celery.contrib.methods.html

**Be aware**: support for `contrib.methods` removed from Celery **since 4.0**

Comment: Would be great to see this in a future version!

Comment: @ThiefMaster This is already in Celery 3.0 actually, see `celery.contrib.methods`: http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/reference/celery.contrib.methods.html

Comment: Ah nice, consider updating your answer to include this.

Comment: Please note: This appears to be removed in Oct 2014 due to it being too buggy to be useful - https://github.com/celery/celery/commit/4f43276c236bbef7239a49b93815f478aec1d9f6

Answer (score 11):

Jeremy Satterfield has a clean and straight forward tutorial to write class based tasks if that's what you want to accomplish. You can check it [here](http://jsatt.com/blog/class-based-celery-tasks/).

The magic is basically extending `celery.Task` class including a `run()` method, like something like this:

```py
from celery import Task

class CustomTask(Task):
    ignore_result = True

    def __init__(self, arg):
        self.arg = arg

    def run(self):
        do_something_with_arg(self.arg)
```

and then run the task like this:

```py
your_arg = 3

custom_task = CustomTask()
custom_task.delay(your_arg)
```

I am not sure if `ignore_result = True` part is necessary or not.

Comment: I tried this, but its not working, its throwing this error - AttributeError: FileTask instance has no attribute 'delay'

Comment: you should not override init in the classbased task.
@SheeshMohsin please remove init and directly get arg in run function
def run(self, arg):
        do_something_with_arg(arg)

Comment: I think you still need to register the task to celery explicitly

Answer (score 5):

When you have:

```
    a = A()
```

you can do:

```
    A.foo.delay(a, param0, .., paramN)
```

Cheers

Comment: How to do the same with `apply_async`, just to get the syntax at one place?

Answer (score 2):

I ran into a similar situation and decided to wrap class methods within a simple function that would redirect its parameters to an instance of the class and it's execution of such methods:

```py
class A:
    def foo(self, bar):
       # do this

a = A()

@app.task
def a_wrapper(bar):
    return a.foo(bar)

# probably in a different size with an import in-place:

a_wrapper.delay(bar)
```

Answer (score 1):

For me the only one that works is celery.current_app because just this passes `self` to the method.

So this should look like this:

```
from celery import current_app
from celery.contrib.methods import task_method

class A:
@current_app.task(filter=task_method, name='A.foo')
def foo(self, bar):
    ...
```

The name must be used if you have method with the same name in different classes.

Comment: as @asksol mentioned this is deprecated since celery version 4 http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/history/whatsnew-4.0.html#unscheduled-removals