# Chain and group tasks methods with celery

Tags: python, django, celery, django-celery

(is that ok? xD)

Well, I have the following situation in a project with Celery. Let me put you all in context.

I had a lot of tasks that consume an API to make some configurations in a service we use via web services (SOAP, i'm using suds for this but that's another story).

So, I realized that all the tasks were almost the same thing until some point of the configuration everything was like the same flow:

configure_this -> configure_some_special_case_things -> configure_other_things -> configure_another_set_of_things

Since the order is not important, I can configure the special case things at the end of the process without any problem, and all the steps but the "special_case_configurations" were the same in all cases, so I abstracted this logic into something like this:

```
class BaseConfigurator(object):
    def __init__(self, some_args, *args, **kwargs):
        self.shared_state = some_args

    def _configure_this(self):
        #some steps that modifies the shared state

    def _configure_other_things(self):
        #some other steps that modifies the shared state

    def _configure_another_set_of_things(self):
        # another set of steps that modifies the shared state

    def _special_case_steps(self):
        # to be implemented by subclasses
        pass

    def configure(self):
        self._configure_this()
        self._configure_ahother_things()
        self._configure_another_set_of_things()
        self._special_case_steps()
```

then... I subclass this one and implement the _special_case_steps

```
class ParticularConfigurator(BaseConfigurator):
    def __init__(self, some_args, *args, **kwargs):
        super(ParticularConfigurator, self).__init__(self, some_args, *args, **kwargs)

    def _special_case_steps(self):
        # actual implementation, this overwrites the parent's "pass"
```

So, the way it used to work was with several "configurator" tasks that called the "general configurators" tasks and the "special case configurator" task in order into a celery.chain, so, I had a lot of duplicated code, I think this way is more elegant and this way I can reuse my "configure" method properly.

I'm aware of this
[using class methods as celery tasks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9250317/using-class-methods-as-celery-tasks)

And all the naming caveats, but for any reason I tried to group and chain some task_methods and I got several pickling errors with objects that i'm not using directly in my task code, I use them in functions that are called by my task_method.

I got it working by instantiating my configurator class in a separate task that discriminates which case are we configuring and decides which configurator to call.

```
@celery.task(queue='user_tasks', max_retries=3, default_retry_delay=120, on_success=handlers.configuration_success)
def run_configuration(case, data):
    switch = {
        'default': DefaultConfigurator # I know, this is not declared but it's just for the example, let's pretend it is a subclass of BaseConfigurator :-)
        'custom': ParticularConfigurator
    }
    switch[case](data).configure()
```

Now, i'm worried about this, because i'm not taking advantage of celery's capabilities with celery.chain and celery.group and I guess this way my code will run slower than if I was able to chain and group task_methods, am I right?

Should I be subclassing Task instead of making tasks out of instance methods?

Thank you for taking the time to read.

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Comment: Nope, I left that company a while ago and i think that's the same code running on production until today. :-(. If you manage to solve it, please post an answer.