# How to make any method from view/model as celery task

Tags: python, django, celery, django-celery

I have some of the analytics methods in `models.py` under `class Analytics` (e.g: `Analytics.record_read_analytics()`). And we are calling those methods for recording analytics, which doesn't need to be synchronous. Currently it's affecting rendering of each request so decided to add these methods in celery queue. We are already using celery for some of our tasks hence we have `tasks.py` and `celery.py` file.

**Following is section of `models.py` file:**

```
class Analytics():
    ...
    ...

    @staticmethod
    def method_a():
        ...
        ...


    def method_b():
        ...
        ...

    @staticmethod
    def record_read_analytics():
        ...
        ...
```

I don't wanted to write again same model level class methods in `tasks.py` and wanted to make some of view method's and model level class methods as celery task.

**Following is `celery.py` file:**

```
from __future__ import absolute_import
from celery import Celery

app = Celery('gnowsys_ndf',
             include=['gnowsys_ndf.tasks'])

app.config_from_object('gnowsys_ndf.celeryconfig')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.start()
```

I'm new to `celery` and looking for help. Thank you in advance.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9250317/using-class-methods-as-celery-tasks

Comment: Passing object arguments to celery function was giving an error but it was not visible to me so used [celery flower](http://flower.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) to dignose the problem and it pointed out correctly. Also thanks to @khajvah and Moinuddin for some useful corrections. Now it's working fine!

Answer (score 3):

You can create tasks out of [methods](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/reference/celery.contrib.methods.html). The bad thing about this is that the object itself gets passed around (because the state of the object in worker has to be same as the state of the caller) in order for it to be called, so you lose some flexibility. So your object has to be pickled every time, which is why I am against this solution. **Of course this concerns only class methods, static methods have no such problem.**

Another solution, which I like, is to create separate tasks.py or class based tasks and call the methods from within them. This way, you will have FULL control over Analytics object within your worker.

Answer (score 0):

You may achieve it like:

```
analytics = Analytics()   # Object of Analytics class
Analytics.record_read_analytics.delay()
```

Also, you need to add `@task` decorator with the `record_read_analytics` function

Comment: I tried this but task is not going to celery queue. Actually task is not getting register.

Comment: check that your message broker service i running

Comment: is the above code throwing some error or exiting without any action?

Comment: Also check you have included your `models.py`, i.e. `include=['gnowsys_ndf.tasks', 'models.py']`

Comment: Yes. I agree with khajvah. And you also need to restart the celery service in order to make these changer reflect with celery process

Comment: Thank you @khajvah and Moinuddin for your help. These were small points to be corrected as well as some code or argument needs to be change. I fixed this and now it's working!