# Calling instance method of class using celery in Python

Tags: django, python-3.x, celery, abstract-class, django-celery

In older version of [Celery](http://www.celeryproject.org/) there was facility of converting instance method to celery task like example below according to http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/3.1/reference/celery.contrib.methods.html

```
from celery.contrib.methods import task
class X(object):
    @task()
    def add(self, x, y):
        return x + y
```

I am using Celery 4.1 which does not have such feature by default. How can I achieve this facility by my own in some simple way?

Let me represent my requirement by example.

```
from abc import ABC, abstractmethod

AbstractService(ABC):

    def __init__(self, client_id, x, y):
        self.client_id = client_id
        self.x = x
        self.y = y

    @abstractmethod
    def preProcess(self):
        '''Some common pre processing will execute here'''

    @abstractmethod
    def process(self):
        '''Some common processing will execute here'''

    @abstractmethod
    def postProcess(self):
        '''Some common post processing will execute here'''

Client1Service(AbstractService):

    def __init__(self, x, y):
        super(__class__, self).__init__('client1_id', x, y)

    # I want to run this using celery
    def preProcess(self):
        super().preProcess()

    # I want to run this using celery
    def process(self):
        data = super().process()
        # apply client1 rules to data
        self.apply_rules(data)
        print('task done')

    # I want to run this using celery
    def postProcess(self):
        super().postProcess()  

    def appy_rules(self, data):
        '''Client 1 rules to apply'''
        # some logic
```

I want to run `preProcess`, `process` and `postProcess` of `Client1Service` class using celery inside [django](https://www.djangoproject.com/) project.

If I will not get any solution then I would have to run logic of preProcess, process and postProcess in some outside celery task that would be little messy.
Suggest me some design for this requirement.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [using class methods as celery tasks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9250317/using-class-methods-as-celery-tasks)

Answer (score -1):

Try using:

```
from celery import shared_task
@shared_task(bind=True)
def yourfunction():
    dosth()
```

Here a good tutorial: http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/django/first-steps-with-django.html

Comment: In my case methods are inside class. `@shared_task(bind=True)` on instance method is not working.

Comment: I see - try this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9250317/using-class-methods-as-celery-tasks, it makes your class extend celery.Task.