# How to run @classmethod as a Celery task in Django?

Tags: python, django, celery

How to run @classmethod as a Celery task in Django? Here is example code:

```
class Notification(TimeStampedModel):
    ....
    @classmethod
    def send_sms(cls, message, phone, user_obj=None, test=False):    
        send_message(frm=settings.NEXMO_FROM_NUMBER, to=phone, text=message)

        return cls.objects.create(
            user=user_obj,
            email="",
            phone=phone,
            text_plain=message,
            notification_type=constants.NOTIFICATION_TYPE_SMS,
            sent=True,
        )

n = Notification()
n.send_sms(message='test', phone='1512351235')
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [using class methods as celery tasks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9250317/using-class-methods-as-celery-tasks)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can wrap it in a celery task like this.

```
from celery import shared_task

@shared_task
def sample_task(message, phone):
  Notification.send_sms(message, phone)
```

and call it this way:

```
sample_task.delay(message='test', phone='1512351235')
```

Don't forget to perform first steps of configuration of Celery in your Django project which is described [here](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/django/first-steps-with-django.html).